# Solving and understanding a formula

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

In my algorithm class, I was given this formula:
$$ \frac{2^{k} -1}{2-1} + 2^{k-1} = 3.2^{k-1} - 1$$
But really I don't see how my professor came up with the right hand side! In fact, I would've said:
$$ \frac{2^{k} -1}{2-1} + 2^{k-1} = 2^k+2^{k-1} - 1$$

Kindly, which one is correct and why?
Thank you

Comment: I assume in stead of $2^{k+1}$ you mean $2^{k-1}$ in the last expression?

Comment: Yes .. I am sorry I will correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in stead of $2^{k+1}$ you mean $2^{k-1}$ in the last expression. Then both are correct:
$$\frac{2^k-1}{2-1}+2^{k-1}=2^k+2^{k-1}-1=2\times2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}-1=3\times2^{k-1}-1.$$